# MySQL timestamps and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

having read noumerous guides I still cannot find a solution that solves my problem..

I have a download.php page that serves downloads.
Ive created a new mysql table called "downloads" where I want to store downloads or whatever.

What I want to do with timestamps is basically a check to see if that IP has downloaded in the last 24 hours and if it has not, add it to the downloads table for the next check.

Or even easier: Add every downloads.php call to the downloads table, saving an IP address and a timestamp.  That timestamp is zhen checked before a download and if the users IP is present in the DB, do x.

Any suggestions?

Notes: A file.php exists. Users visit pages like file.php/filexxx and click on download. download.php then performs a bunch of checks and serves the file. With that I want to limit downloads if the user has downloaded x files in the last 24 hours. Im currently using cookies and this is not an optimum solution. Any help?!

Much appreciated!!

Comment: What is the *specific* question. Your question now amounts to "Any suggestions?"

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysql TimeDiff function to get total hours.IF it is more than 24 hours. Insert again as a new count.Also combine the IP validation with your query.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(now(),first_downloaded_time) ,ip from downloads where ip='$ip'
```

first_downloaded_time is the column which stores timestamp;

Run the above query and you will get timestatmp like '23:43:44';
Use substr() method to get only hours

```
substr('23:43:44',0,2);//this will output 23
```

Use this value to insert downloads ip, if it is greater than 23 or no value(for newer entry)